# How can I get item views from ebay api for my seller account?

Tags: xml, ebay-api, traffic

I have a seller and a developer account for the ebay api. I need to get traffic data, specifically the number of times one of my items was viewed. I think I can do this by retrieving my items with GetSellerList which should include a HitCount attribute, but it returns an empty ItemArray object even though I'm sure the seller account has items.

Here is the body of the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>access_token</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
  <AdminEndedItemsOnly>False</AdminEndedItemsOnly>
  <GranularityLevel>Medium</GranularityLevel>
  <IncludeVariations>True</IncludeVariations>
  <IncludeWatchCount>True</IncludeWatchCount>
  <Pagination> PaginationType
    <EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
  </Pagination>
  <Sort>1</Sort>
  <StartTimeFrom>2022-04-15T19:09:02.768Z</StartTimeFrom>
  <StartTimeTo>2022-04-21T16:09:02.768Z</StartTimeTo>
  <!-- Standard Input Fields -->
  <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
  <!-- ... more DetailLevel values allowed here ... -->
  <ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
  <MessageID> string </MessageID>
  <WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
</GetSellerListRequest>
```

Here are the headers:

```
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: app_name
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetSellerList
X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING: XML
X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: some_code
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: some code
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 825
Content-Type: text/xml
```

And the url : https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll

method: POST.

I can't figure out why I keep getting the following response with no items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSellerListResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2022-04-21T14:44:03.680Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <CorrelationID> string </CorrelationID>
    <Version>1173</Version>
    <Build>E1173_CORE_APISELLING_19187371_R1</Build>
    <ItemArray/>
</GetSellerListResponse>
```

I have tried playing with the date range and the GranularityLevel, but I still get an empty ItemArray.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is to get item view count of your item only, the easiest and best solution is to add a tracking pixel/web beacon in each listing in way to get not only the count of views but also date, time and location of viewer.

Comment: this is different from the HitCount attribute right? Why would I do this if I can already enable a HitCount?

Comment: Well, IMHO, `HitCount` is not reliable: if you check a just created listing you will find between 3 to 6 visits and this is unreasonable, but this is (perhaps) a minor issue.
I think it is much better to know, WHEN people visit my listings, and their location.

Comment: If this is still not enough... you should anyway consider that among `Deprecation and Dismissions` it is written:
`HitCounter` and `HitCount` fields will be decommissioned on April 30, 2022 in the `Trading` and `Shopping` APIs. In the `Trading API`, this change affects `GetItem`, `GetBidderList`, `GetSellerList`, and `GetSellerEvents`. For `Shopping API`, this change affects `GetSingleItem` and `GetMultipleItems`

Comment: thanks, do you have a link for an example on how to add this tracking pixel/beacon? Also, would adding this allow me to see only which ebay users viewed the page or would it detect any view?

Comment: tracking pixel is not a function but a technique: you should first try to understand what it is and how it works.
you can find everything here on SO or with google.

Comment: one last question: If you incorporate a tracking pixel, does the user have to scroll over it in order for the view to be registered, or is it registered simply by loading the page in the browser?

Comment: Technically it is not required to scroll, but there is a lot of js in an eBay listing, therefore if some pieces of the DOM are rendered via javascript it could happen that it is not triggered. But you can put it on top of the listing to avoid any risk. But there's a problem on mobile devices: here the template it is not loaded until the use click on "Show Description" therefore it is triggered only if such event occour.